# Getting symfony console arguments after double dash

Tags: symfony-console

I'm trying to build sophisticated command:

```
bin/console remote:exec [stage] [revision] -- arguments...
```

`stage` and `revision` arguments are optional (they are derived from current git revision, if omitted), while `arguments` is a variable length array of words that form command to be executed on remote host - and it gets tricky to find out if first argument is `stage`, `revision`, or part of `arguments`. Is it possible to get all Symfony command arguments that were specified after double dash, so i could segregate arguments?

Comment: It seems that at this moment the whole argument(s) array needs to be fetched (and parsed).

Comment: Evidence backing up @imme assertion: https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Tests/Input/ArgvInputTest.php#L283-L293